# nocite by selection

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies

I want to create a bibliography selecting all items from a large bib file which contain a specific author and were published in a specific year.

So far I see the nocite command only with * which is everything or specifying single items by hand but not seen any example with a more general rule.

printbibliography seems to take some rules, but first tests show that items will not be sequentially numerated, since it selects them from the full list.

I could import the bib file in some GUI tool like Zotero, select there the items I want and export it as new file again, but I would like to have a solution which stays in TeX land and can for example be expanded for automation selecting different years, authors etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with Biblatex and "source maps" that ignore the entries we are not interested in:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{one,
  author={Someone Else},
  year={2014},
  title={Uninteresting book},
}
@book{two,
  author={This Author},
  year={1999},
  title={Book that's too early},
}
@book{three,
  author={Author, This},
  year={2014},
  title={An interesting book},
}
@book{four,
  author={This Author},
  year={2014},
  title={Another interesting book},
}
@book{five,
  author={Someone Else and This Author},
  year={2014},
  title={Joint effort},
}
\end{filecontents}
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps{
    \map{
      % Remove those not by chosen author
      \step[fieldsource=author,
            notmatch=\regexp{Author,\s+This|This\s+Author},
            final]
      \step[entrynull]
    }
    \map{
      % Remove those not from chosen year
      \step[fieldsource=year,
            notmatch={2014},
            final]
      \step[entrynull]
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

You'd have to write an regexp matching the author name. This only looks at the `author` field. One might want to use extra rules for `editor` field and others.

Comment: Thank you! What I didn't mention, I'm also interested into turning the whole thing into a rtf with latex2rtf. This one works with classic bibtex but doesnt seem to take biblatex.

Answer (score 0):

bib2bib was what I was looking for. (contra intuitively contained in the package bibtex2html)